# How to create polymorphic/generic many-to-many relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, associations

I would like to create a generic many-to-many relationship (List).

Using the following example domain:

```
+-------+  +----------+ +-----------+
| Issue |  | Web Page | | Wiki Page |  
+-------+  +----------+ +-----------+
```

I woulk like to create a generic link association like the following, where `from` and `to` may be any of the domain objects above.

```
+---------------------+ 
| Link                |
+---------------------+ 
| Object: from        |
| Object: to          |
| String: description |
+---------------------+
```

So `Issue` has-many `Link`, where the issue is in one side of the relationship.

I envisage using a link table that will look something like the following:

```
Link Table
| ID | SRC_ID | SRC_CLASS | DEST_ID | DESC_CLASS |
```

So `SRC_ID` and `DEST_ID` are foreign keys into the appropriate table.

What should the mapping for the Link table look like?

Answer (score 0):

In `Hibernate` you should not manually create table from `Entity` class. Just put annotation `@ManyToMany` to your pojo and hibernate will generate schema of your database with all your foreign key relationship with related tables.

Hibernate Many-To-Many uni-directional mapping should like:

```
@Entity
class Issue{
  @ManyToMany
  List<Link> links;
}

@Entity
class Link{
}
```

If your application is Java SE, then use class `SchemaExport` to generate schema in database.

Comment: Yes I understand all that - but the reason for adding in an example for the table structure was to give you an idea for what I am looking for.  Since the `to` and `from` ends of the relation can be multiple types, I'm not sure how to code the Link itself

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this relationship by externalising it entirely from the domain objects.

Example (Groovy+Grails)

```
class Link{
   String fromClass
   long fromId
   String toClass
   long toId
   String description

   Link(){}
   Link(Object src, Object dest, String descrption){
      fromClass=src.class.name
      fromId=src.id
      toClass=dest.class.name
      toId=dest.id
      this.description=description
   }

   Object getFrom(){
      // Invoke GORM static finder
      Class.forName(fromClass)."get"(fromId)
   }

   Object getTo(){
      // Invoke GORM static finder
      Class.forName(toClass)."get"(toId)
   }
}
```

With an associated service layer to create/retrieve the objects:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
class LinkableService {
  @Transactional
  public void link(Object src, Object dest, String description){
    Link link = new Link(src,dest,description)
    link.save()
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public Collection<Link> links(Object subject){
    def fromLinks = Link.findAllWhere(fromClass:subject.class.name, fromId:subject.id)
    def toLinks = Link.findAllWhere(toClass:subject.class.name, toId:subject.id)
    def allLinks = new ArrayList<Link>(fromLinks)
    allLinks.addAll(toLinks)
    return allLinks
  }

}
```

I am a little concerned about performance, but as I only expect to be working with small datasets it should not be a major issue.  And without metrics, I won't optimise yet!

But is there a better solution?